# Why keras use "call" instead of __call__?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I fond the following code in (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_layers)

```
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_variable("kernel",
                                shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
                                       self.num_outputs])

  def call(self, input):
    return tf.matmul(input, self.kernel)
```

The last two lines is call method, while it does not like usual python class method  **call** with two underlines. Is any differences between those?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following answer is based on https://tf.wiki/zh/basic/models.html.

Basically in Python, when you call an instance from class `ClassA` using `ClassA()`, it is equivalent to `ClassA.__call__()`. So it seems reasonable to use `__call__()` instead of `call()` in this case, right?

However, the reason we use `call()` is that when `tf.keras` calls a model or a layer, it has its own inner operations which are essential to keep its inner structure. As a result, it exposes a method `call()` for custom overloading. `__call__()` calls `call()` as well as some inner operations, so when we overload `call()` inheriting from `tf.keras.Model` or `tf.keras.Layer`, we can call our custom code while keeping `tf.keras`'s inner structure.

For example, from my experience, if your input is a numpy array instead of a tensor, you don't need to transform it manually if you write custom code in `call()` but if you overwrite `__call__()`, it would be a problem since some inner operations are not called.

Comment: all that @junhuizh I agree with.  Too add to that.  **never** call .call().  Please see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#call for better understanding.  .call() can be overridden by the user but the user must never call it.