# TensorFlow: Difference between functioning of __call__() and call() when designing custom layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I've designed a neural network with a custom layer in TensorFlow. Firstly, I used `__call__()` to define the forward pass and then I called the `model.summary()`. This gave me following error

```
ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.
```

However, when I replaced it with `call()`, It worked just fine.

Q: I want to understand what is going on under the hood.

Edit:
I haven't created `build()` and have declared everything in `__init__()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ValueError` you've faced is reasonable. This is asked and get answered already over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908188/this-model-has-not-yet-been-built-error-on-model-summary) And also the difference between `call` and `__call__` is also answered already over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103604/why-keras-use-call-instead-of-call);(as you didn't give any code to reproduce so I'm referring to this link). However, FYI, I've written an article about model subclassing and custom training from scratch, I hope the modeling approach part may give you some insight (the article [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/model-sub-classing-and-custom-training-loop-from-scratch-in-tensorflow-2-cc1d4f10fb4e)).

#### Update

Too many questions in the comment section, so I like to add my response here. Basically, the [`__call__`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4343d75c5153470198d970166497fb5b9c4961f5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L869) method is implemented in the [`Layer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4343d75c5153470198d970166497fb5b9c4961f5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L103) class.  And this layer class is inherited by the `Model` class. Let's say

```py
import inspect
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

# inspect.getmro(CLASS) returns a tuple of class CLASS's base classes, 
# including CLASS, in Method Resolution Order (MRO).
inspect.getmro(Model)

# out
(tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model,
tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer.Layer,...)
```

Now, in `__call__` method in the `Layer` class has assigned [`self.call`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4343d75c5153470198d970166497fb5b9c4961f5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L965) method to `call_fn`. Which is further used [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4343d75c5153470198d970166497fb5b9c4961f5/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L979). Such as:

```py
def __call__(self, input):
    call_fn = self.call
    outputs = call_fn(input, ...)
    return outputs
```

So when we call our `Model` class instance, it's inherited `__call__` method (from `Layer` class) will be executed automatically, which calls our own `call` method.

**Model Summary**

The modeling with Subclassing API is not as same as Sequential or Functional API.  It is not graph networks and therefore only a node containing the model name would be plotted with these models. We can't really assume anything about the structure of a subclassed Model. That's why we can't get the output shape. However, there's a workaround to get the facilities of model shape summary and plot it either conveniently. Check [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31647#issuecomment-692586409).

Comment: I don't have any  ```build()``` method in my code so can't call ```model.build()```. Also, I have already read both of the link you have shared.

Comment: If I use ```call()``` then my code works fine. So no problem there. What I wanted as an answer for this question is, what functionalities does a ```call``` method invoke in ```tf.keras.layers.Layer``` that ```__call__``` is not evoking, that causes this error. Anyway glad somebody responded.

Comment: I have gone through your article on TDS. I liked how how used ```build_graph```. That was clever. Otherwise we don't get output shape. I wonder, why that could be happening?

Comment: Also, have you tried ```tf.keras.utils.plot_model```. Let me know what you get :)