# When and How the Call function work in Model Subclassing of Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, subclassing

I read in **Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and Tensorflow** about using the Sub-classing API to build dynamic models which mainly involves writing a subclass with two methods in it: the constructor and a call function. The constructor is fairly easy to understand. However, I had problem understanding when and how the call function work exactly when the model is being built.

I used code from the book and experiment a bit as below(using California housing dataset from sklearn):

```
class WideAndDeepModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units=30, activation='relu', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
        self.hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
        self.main_output = keras.layers.Dense(1)
        self.aux_output = keras.layers.Dense(1)
    def call(self, inputs):
        print('call function running')
        input_A, input_B = inputs
        hidden1 = self.hidden1(input_B)
        hidden2 = self.hidden2(hidden1)
        concat = keras.layers.concatenate([input_A, hidden2])
        main_output = self.main_output(concat)
        aux_output = self.aux_output(hidden2)
        return main_output, aux_output

model = WideAndDeepModel()
model.compile(loss=['mse','mse'], loss_weights=[0.9,0.1], optimizer='sgd')
history = model.fit([X_train_A, X_train_B],[y_train, y_train], epochs=20, validation_data=([X_val_A, X_val_B], [y_val, y_val]))
```

Below is the output during training:

```
Epoch 1/20
***call function running***
***call function running***
353/363 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6398 - output_1_loss: 1.5468 - output_2_loss: 2.4769
***call function running***
363/363 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.6224 - output_1_loss: 1.5296 - output_2_loss: 2.4571 - val_loss: 4.3588 - val_output_1_loss: 4.7174 - val_output_2_loss: 1.1308
Epoch 2/20
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.6073 - output_1_loss: 0.5492 - output_2_loss: 1.1297 - val_loss: 75.1126 - val_output_1_loss: 81.6632 - val_output_2_loss: 16.1572
...
```

The call function gets run twice at the beginning of training through the first epoch and then gets run almost at the end of the first epoch. It is never run after that.

This looks to me that while the layers are instantiated early in the constructor function, the connection between the layers(defined in the call function) are established quite late(at the start of the training). It also looks to me that there is no logic entities of this so called connection between the layers, the connection is just a process of passing the output of one layer to another in a specific order. Is my understanding correct?

The second question is why the call function gets run three times at the early stage of the training instead of just once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TensorFlow: Difference between functioning of \_\_call\_\_() and call() when designing custom layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64840898/tensorflow-difference-between-functioning-of-call-and-call-when-designi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the layers are instantiated early in the constructor function

Correct

> the connection between the layers are established quite late

Also correct, the weights are initialized when you call `model.build()` or call the model for the first time, as you can see in this [guide](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing) to subclass Keras layers:

```
class Linear(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
```

> why the call function gets run three times at the early stage

Probably the first time is when the model was called for the first time, and the weights were instantiated. Then another time to build the Tensorflow graph, which is non-Python code than runs Tensorflow models. The model is called once to create this graph, and further calls are outside of Python so your print function is no longer part of it. You can change this behavior by using `model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`. Finally, the third time would be the first time the validation data is passed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all be aware that using python print statements is not a good idea when using `model.compile()` and `model.fit()` is not a good idea for debugging your model since tensorflow use C++ to run the training faster and in parallel and this print statements will be omitted.
But let me back to your question. It is good to mention that TensorFlow and Keras models have lazy behavior, that means when you instantiate the model `model = WideAndDeepModel()`, the model weights are not created yet, and they will be created whether you call the  the `model.call()` for the first time or `model.build()` method. So in seems that your model have been called in python once for creating model weights, once for starting training procedure and build the C++ object (graph), and once for starting the validation. After that all computations will be performed in C++ and you don't see any print statement.

Note: if you want to print something in graph mode you can use `tf.print`

Comment: Can you provide a reference on the C++ part? I'd like to read more about this

Comment: I think this TensorFlow official [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs) is a good starting point.