# Why can I use model(x, training =True) when I define my own call function without the arguement 'training'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, class, machine-learning, deep-learning

Notice when I created my model, I defined the call function with argument something = False,
when I used the model in function train_step, I put in "something =True, training = True", training is not defined in my call, but it is in the default tf.keras.model call.
Why am I able to execute this with no error? and the output basically prints a bunch of 'my call's.

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

# Add a channels dimension
x_train = x_train[..., tf.newaxis].astype("float32")
x_test = x_test[..., tf.newaxis].astype("float32")

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (x_train, y_train)).shuffle(10000).batch(32)

class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.fl = Flatten()
    self.d = Dense(10)
  
  ######My problem#######
  def call(self, x, something=False):
    if something:
      tf.print('my call')
    x = self.fl(x)
    return self.d(x)


model = MyModel()
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

@tf.function
def train_step(X,Y):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    ######My problem#######
    predictions = model(X, something =True, training = True)
    loss = loss_object(Y, predictions)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

for epoch in range(3):

  for X,Y in train_ds:
    train_step(X,Y)
```

Comment: strangely, `predictions = model.call(X, something =True, training = True)`  raises the error `TypeError: tf__call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'training'`

Comment: @elbe it's not strange at all considering that `call != __call__` (see the answer).

Answer (score 1):

In the Model class, the [call method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#call) documentation :

> To call a model on an input, always use the `__call__()̀` method, i.e.
> model(inputs), which relies on the underlying `call()` method.

And indeed, the `__call__` can take any input argument : `def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):` ([in Model class source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/engine/training.py#L459-L490))

You can find a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64840898/tensorflow-difference-between-functioning-of-call-and-call-when-designi)